# Join single table

Tags: mysql

I know this question is one a bloody beginner asks, but can anyone be as kind as to look at this code:

```
SELECT w.word 
FROM words
AS w
INNER JOIN words as w1 ON w.meaning=w1.meaning
AND w1.word='word1'
```

The table looks like this:

```
id meaning word
 1       1 word1
 2       1 word2
 3       1 word3
 4       2 word4
 5       2 word5
 6       3 word6
```

The code above gives the result Violine, Fiedel and Geige...but I want the word I've been searching for not to be included in the result. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you also put the final result you want to see if the table is the one as you have written above? Or, let us know in plain english what is it that you want to know from this table?

Comment: maybe change = with <> or != ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply filter it in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT w.word 
FROM words
AS w
INNER JOIN words as w1 ON w.meaning=w1.meaning
AND w1.word  = 'Violine'
AND w.word <> w1.word
```

Answer (score 3):

You want all the results where w1.word is Violine, except the one where w.word itself is Violine?

```
SELECT w.word 
FROM words
AS w
INNER JOIN words as w1 ON w.meaning=w1.meaning
AND w1.word='Violine'
AND w.word <> 'Violine'
```